# Libgdx : Export to runnable Jar

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So I manage to export my game to a runnable jar without errors, but when I run it the window opens and closes quickly.

Does anyone know a good guide on how to make a runnable jar out of your application?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to make an executable out of my libgdx game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029028/how-to-make-an-executable-out-of-my-libgdx-game)

Answer (score 1):

Run it from the command line to see the error message. Usually it's something to do with the manifest not listing the main class.

[this may help](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_executable_JAR_file_for_a_stand-alone_SWT_program?)